# In React Native, Is there way to stop the "use strong password" suggestion from appearing when doing "confirm password" input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

On a sign up screen I made, I have a "New Password" and "Confirm Password" input tag, but the "Use Strong Password?" option appears when clicking on Confirm Password. Is there a way to get this to not appear, but still hide the input (*)? Here is my code:

```
  <Input
    secureTextEntry
    label="Create Password"
    value={password}
    onChangeText={setPassword}
    textContentType="newPassword"
    returnKeyType="done"
    leftIcon={{
      type: "material-community-icons",
      name: "lock",
      color: colors.text,
    }}
    inputStyle={{ color: colors.text }}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
  />
  <Input
    // secureTextEntry
    label="Confirm your Password"
    value={confirmPassword}
    onChangeText={setConfirmPassword}
    textContentType="newPassword"
    returnKeyType="done"
    leftIcon={{
      type: "material-community-icons",
      name: "lock",
      color: colors.text,
    }}
    inputStyle={{ color: colors.text }}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    errorMessage={localErrorMessage}
  />
```